# How to setup django migrations to be always the last one applied

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have django application and migration file `002_auto.py`, which uses [Django RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) to alter database. I have no idea how much migrations files would be created in future, but I want the file `002_auto.py` to be applied as the last part of migration process.

**How to set that migrations to be executed as the last one while performing django migrations without need to perform any manual steps each time I want to execute `migrate` command (or altering `dependencies` variable each time i've added new migrations)?**

**p.s.** I've looked into django migrations documentation and other articles without success.

Comment: what is the reason why you want this? it somewhat goes against the idea of using migrations in the fist place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass `migrate` command and put this code after `super` call

```
# project/myapp/management/commands/custom_migrate.py
from django.core.management.commands.migrate import Command as MigrateCommand

class Command(MigrateCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        super().handle(*args, **options)
        # put your code from 002_auto.py here
```

This command should be added to app that is in your INSTALLED_APPS. And then you can call it like this

```
python manage.py custom_migrate
```

Read more about custom commands https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Is there are any way's to avoid calling custom_migrate separately (call it within execution of `migrate`?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko If you want you can try naming it just `migrate` and manage.py will use your version of `migrate` instead of default one. It should work, but I didn't checked.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use `post_migrate` signal in one of your models, and put the code you call in `002_auto.py` to signal hanlder.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-migrate

Comment: Unfortunattely it won't work for me as RunPython alters database, which is prohibited in case of using  post_migrate

Comment: OK, maybe you can put the desired logic into an raw-SQL query(ies)?

Answer (score 1):

If a migration, needs to be applied in a certain order then that isn't ever going to work (regardless of whatever hacky solution you try out).

Chances are at some point in the future you're going to introduce a change that would mean having this last wouldn't make any sense.

Your best option is to make a custom management command and/or bash script and then use that to migrate and alter your database.